# Store direct_url in category text in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, geturl

We are moving our shop to Magento 2 and I just noticed that the store direct_url is not working anymore in our category texts. Does anyone know how you have to put this in Magento 2.

We have it in Magento 1 as following:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url=""}}">text</a>
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{{store url=''}}">text</a>
```

will work in Magento 2

Comment: Hi Jaimin, this link does work, but there is a strange thing going on. When you place it like that he will put a / after the url so domain.com/link/ instead of domain.com/link. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Btw in a static block the store direct_url="" is working